# How to use SVM trained on Weka for real time processing with python

Tags: python, weka

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use a support vector machine trained on Weka for real time processing with python.

For example when you train a back propagation algorithm on Matlab, you can extract the weights and biases and use them to replicate the network on other programs (e.g python) in feed-forward.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You can use [`sklearn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) library , and use `svm` that defined there.

Comment: @Arman, can you give more details? I have sklearn installed already

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to continue using Python and Weka, the easiest way is to just call the Weka command line using `subprocess` (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). You can then train and save your models and use them as needed. See this reference: https://weka.wikispaces.com/Saving+and+loading+models

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I'm currently using sklearn, I will implement your suggestions later. Thanks again.